# CucumberRunner show progress of how many scenarios left to be excecuted

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, acceptance-testing, runner

I have a lot of Acceptance tests that runs with CucumberRunner. When it starts I have no idea in awhile how many scenarios left to be executed. Is there any way how i can print in the terminal like:

**Scenario(10 of 1000) Call A() will add new object**

**Scenario(11 of 1000) Call B() will open new window**

....

etc

Regards

Comment: Use the Before global hook. Place a static int variable in the stepdefinition java class and increment it each time. Print it or log the value. Do remember for scenario outline, this will get incremented for each row of the example table. No idea about getting the total scenario count.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [QAF Gherkin client](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) it has [live reporting](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_reporting.html) feature which not only shows you the total vs completed test count but you also can see detailed report of completed test during execution.